# Reducing the FOV of VLP-16 affects it Packet Rate per second

Tags: mapping, lidar, fieldofview

I have recently started working on velodyne VLP-16.
I came to an understanding that VLP-16 has a standard packet rate of 754 packets/second. For 600RPM i will have 75.4 packets per revolution.

**Question**

1. Does reducing the FOV will affect my packet rate or it will still send 75.4 packets.
2. 75.4 packets can only be needed if FOV is 360 degreees, right.
3. Is packet rate independent of FOV.
4. If its dependent, will i have empty packets if  i dont need the full 360 degrees
5. If i have empty packets, how do i filter out the empty ones

Thank you and let me know if these even make any sense